# Bootstrap dropdown alignment off after loading dropdown contents dynamically in Blazor

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side, popper.js

In Blazor, you can load content dynamically by putting it in an `@if` block and then making that condition true, e.g. on a button click.

I have a Bootstrap dropdown whose contents are loaded when the dropdown is first clicked. For some reason, the right alignment is not honored on the first click of the dropdown button but is on each subsequent click to open it. There is something about the initial render and the CSS not being honored. I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is an example (Blazor server-side): https://blazorfiddle.com/s/yc5m9rv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bootstrap dropdowns user popper.js, the solution was found through that. Bootstrap provides an `update` method to refresh the dropdown's position.

To solve this issue, the `update` method just needed to be called after the dropdown is rendered.

Here is an update, with this solution, to the example in the question: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/t24r1753